# Listen to stream from /dev/tty where return key is not necessary

Tags: stdin, tty, keystroke

Is there a way to read a stream from /dev/tty, and make it unnecessary to hit the return key to send data there? I want to be able to type a character and have it sent without hitting return/enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a matter of using raw mode, at least with Node.js:

```
const {ReadStream} = require('stream');
const r = new ReadStream();
r.setRawMode(true);
```